# handler or alarm in android service?

Tags: android, handler, alarm, schedule

I have a service that run all time, and I need get Info from my server 2 times per day. must I use a Handler with 12Hs of delay? or an alarm?

can you tell me what is the best option please?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AlarmManager was designed for exactly this kind of a task. It lets you set inexact alarms that Android will group with other tasks to minimize the battery cost associated with waking up the device. If you need to definitely poll the server at a precise time (and it cannot wait until the user wakes up the device), then you can set an exact alarm which will wake up the device and then you can have a method which will automate the creation of another exact alarm scheduled to be executed 12 hours from then.

The drawback with AlarmManager is that the service will not automatically restart if the device turns off and is then turned back on. In this case, you can work around it by having a BroadcastReceiver listen to ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETE. Android 5.0 also provides the JobScheduler API which can persist jobs through system reboots.

Handlers are best used for processes that run for a short time.

Comment: Here you go.. https://github.com/ucsunil/android-todo/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/android/application/services/TaskNotifyService.java. That is a code snippet of a very poorly designed application that I once worked on sometime back for practice. It basically sets an alarm once a user stores a task. You can use this model to schedule exactAlarms().

Comment: For some reason there is something I am doing bad. Because I cann't get the alarmManager launch or do anything..
this is my work:

AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), **ActivateActivity.class**);
intent.setAction("Notification");
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
  manager.set(AlarmManager.RTC, AlarmManager.INTERVAL_HALF_DAY, pi);

Comment: In **ActivateActivity -> OnCreate()** I have this code to get the intent accion, but this never run.

Intent intent = getIntent();
String mTask = intent.getAction();
try {
 if (mTask.equals("Notification")) {
  checkAppNotification();
 }
} catch (Exception e) {
 // TODO: handle exception  
}

Comment: You should not be using getApplicationContext() while starting another activity from one actiivity. Also the intent.getAction() call is used while broadcasting. If you simply want to pass a string "Notification", then use intent.putExtra("notification", "Notification"); and then do intent.getExtra("notification"); to get the String.

Comment: no, the AlarmManager is set in a Service.
maybe I need to write the method I want to trigger in the same service?

Answer (score 0):

Alarm is probably better-  if the app is killed for memory, an alarm will still be in the system.  A handler won't be.  Handlers are best for short (a few second) delays.